# FilesystemIterator is not working

Tags: php

I try to run on all files in `/images` directory and I get disconnected when I reach the constructor part the directory is in the same directory as my php file:

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator('./images/');
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
}
```

The error I see is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message        'FilesystemIterator::__construct(/images/,/images/):
>   The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)' in
>   D:\wamp\www\MyHome2\php\images.php:9

Comment: Filesystem paths should be from the filesystem root; suspect your directory is from your web server htdocs root

Comment: I understand now why it is not working my php file is in /php directory I need to do something with I need to do it like that ../images :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are (probably) using absolute paths when you want relative paths. use

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator('./images/');
```

or in your case, where you need to move "up" one folder, use ".." to move up:

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator('./../images/');
```

Comment: @Canttouchit well, what is the absolute path of the `images` directory?

Comment: D:\wamp\www\MyHome2\images it is working with absolute path but I want to use relative path why is it now working with relative

Comment: use ".." to move "up" one folder: $it = new FilesystemIterator('./../images/');

Answer (score 2):

Your path doesn't exist, you're using an absolute path, change it to relative or give the correct full path.

Example absolute:

```
D:\wamp\www\MyHome2\php\images
```

example relative:

```
./images/
```

You can read about how paths work in file systems here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)